# Python string compare and replace

Tags: python, compare

I have a .txt with:

```
#Date 111111:UhUidsiIds
#Name Sebastian-Forset
#Date 222222:UdfasdUDsa
#Name Sebastian_Forset2
#Date 333333:UDsafduD
#Name Solaris Mage
#Date 444444:Ghdsasra
#Name Marge S
```

and a file whith:

```
#Name Sebastian Forset
#Date 191020
#Name Sebastian Forset2
#Date 201020
#Date Homer S
#Date 281902
```

The names are the same, with some differences of characters (spaces, -, _ etc.)
I would copy the numbers of the second file to the first file in order to have a final file txt with:

```
#Name Sebastian Forset
#Date 191020:UhUidsiIds
#Name Sebastian Forset2
#Date 201020:UdfasdUDsa
#Name Solaris Mage
#Date 281902:UDsafduD
#Name Marge S
#Date 444444:Ghdsasra
```

This is my code, but merge the file, copy only same name

```
def isInFile(l, f):
    with open(f, 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            if l == line:
                return True
        return False

def similitudes(file1, file2):
    same = 0
    data = ''
    copy = False
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            if copy == True:
                data += line
                if line == '\n' or line[0:6] != '#Name ':
                    copy = False
            if (line[0:6] == '#Name ')  or line[0:6] == '#Date ':
                print line
                if isInFile(line, file2) == True:
                    copy = True
                    data += line
                    print "true"
                else:
                    print "ok"
                    same += 1
    return data

def main(argv=2):
    print (sys.argv[1])
    print (sys.argv[2])
    if argv == 2:
        out = open('final.txt', 'w')
        data = (
                similitudes(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) + '\n'
                )
        out.write(data)
        out.close()
    else:
        print ("This program need 2 files")
        exit (0)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
   status = main()
   sys.exit(status)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! What is your actual question? Please show the code you've already written to solve this problem, and where it's not working as expected.

Comment: I would consider the data structure you use when you read the data in (e.g. a `dict`). And the string methods `maketrans()` and `translate()` would allow you to translate the punctuation to spaces to make the names comparable.

Comment: Ok i have adjust my request

Answer (score 1):

First, list out the characters that will differ. Let's say  `"-" , "_" and " ".`

Now split the two strings using these delimiters. you can use **"re"** package in python.

```
>>> a='Mr-Sebastian_Forset '
>>> import re
>>> re.split('- |_ | ',a)
['Mr', 'Sebastian', 'Forset']
```

If the resultant lists for the two strings are equal, paste the number in second file  in first one.

**You can use the same delimiter concept to split the number and paste it in other file.**

Comment: Yes, but this is no solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Read the first file into a dictionary, using `maketrans`/`translate` to clean up the name.
Using `zip(file, file)` to read 2 lines of the file at a time makes it much easier to handle.
And using `.split(' ', 1)[1]` to get rid of the first column.
And `.strip()` to get rid of any surrounding whitespace (i.e. `\n`)

Then you can read the second file updating the dictionary.

In Python3 this looks like:

```
>>> punc = str.maketrans('_-', '  ')   # import string & string.maketrans() in Py2
>>> with open(filename1) as file1, open(filename2) as file2:
...     data = {name.split(' ', 1)[1].strip().translate(punc):
...             date.split(' ', 1)[1].strip().split(':')
...             for name, date in zip(file1, file1)}
...     for n, d in zip(file2, file2):
...         data[n.split(' ', 1)[1].strip()][0] = d.split(' ', 1)[1].strip()
>>> data
{'Marge S': ['444444', 'Ghdsasra'],
 'Sebastian Forset': ['191020', 'UhUidsiIds'],
 'Sebastian Forset2': ['201020', 'UdfasdUDsa'],
 'Solaris Mage': ['281902', 'UDsafduD']}
```

After that it is just a matter of writing the dictionary out to a new file.

```
>>> with open(<output>, 'w+') as output:
...     for name, date in data.items():
...         output.write('#Name {}\n'.format(name))
...         output.write('#Date {}:{}\n'.format(*date))
```

Note: I had to change 'Homer S' to 'Solaris Mage' in the second file to get the stated output.

Comment: Hi thanks for this, but is possible have a complete code? :(

Comment: I have added writing the output but SO isn't really a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

**`Adding another answer, which will points out the bug in your code`**

Coming to the following piece of code

```
if (line[0:6] == '#Name ')  or line[0:6] == '#Date ':
    print line
    if isInFile(line, file2) == True:
        copy = True
        data += line
```

Here, you are checking If your line starts with either `"#Name "` or `"#Date "`, and calling isInFile() method with **line** and **file2** as arguments.

This is the first issue, there is no use of sending just one line that starts with `"#Name "` in your case.

If the current line starts with `"#Date "`, send the previous line and file as arguments to this method.

And second Issue is with the isInFile() definition, which is doing effectively nothing.

```
if l == line:
    return true
```

You are just checking if two lines in file1 and file2 are same and if yes, you writing this line in sysout. 
***So, your program will just print the common lines between file1 and file2.***

Modified code should like the below one:

```
def isInFile(l, f):
    line_found = false
    required_line = null
    with open(f, 'r') as f2:
        for line in f2:
            if line_found:
                required_line = line
                break
            elif l == line:
                line_found = true
    return (line_found, required_line)


def similitudes(file1, file2):
    same = 0
    data = ''
    copy = False
    previous_line = null
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
        for line in f1:
            if copy == True:
                data += line
                if line == '\n' or line[0:6] != '#Name ':
                    copy = False
            if (line[0:6] == '#Name '):
                print line
                previous_line = line
            elif line[0:6] == '#Date ':
                print line
                file2_line_info = isInFile(previous_line, file2)
                if  file2_line_info[0] == True:
                    copy = True
                    data += file2_line_info[1]
                    print "true"
    return data

def main(argv=2):
    print (sys.argv[1])
    print (sys.argv[2])
    if argv == 2:
        out = open('final.txt', 'w')
        data = (
                similitudes(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]) + '\n'
                )
        out.write(data)
        out.close()
    else:
        print ("This program need 2 files")
        exit (0)
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
   status = main()
   sys.exit(status)
```

**Note: This is not the pythonic way of doing things. As I have mentioned in the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34696778/3534696 use "re" module and solve the problem efficiently.**